# What is the proper android view for a list of zoomable & pannable images?

Tags: android, bitmap

My end goal is to create an Activity in Android that displays two or more images in a scrollable vertical list. The problem is I keep trying different Views and I'm not sure what the best choice is for my situation.

The ideal implementation will allow me to do all of the following:

1. Display images asynchronously as they are fetched from the server.
2. Avoid VM memory issues when I have 10+ images.
3. Zoom/pan either all images at once or images in individually

My implementation uses a single bitmap comprised of all the images in a custom SurfaceView but I can already see how it makes #1 and #2 difficult. I only have #3 working.

I've also tried using a ListView but I couldn't successfully implement #3.

I'm relatively new to Android development but the way I see it the custom SurfaceView can give me #3 and a custom ListView can give me #1 and #2. Would creating a ListView comprised of custom SurfaceViews (one per image) be the right approach or am I way off track?  Is there a better approach to my situation?

Comment: Turns out my design is flawed.  I want a to pan the images but it conflicts with the listviews vertical scroll.  When I swipe my finger up and down the listview scrolls while the image pans, not a good design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this by using a ListView comprised of ImageViews.  This resolved #1 and #2.  Then to deal with pan/zoom I added an onClick listener to the rows of the ListView.  This fires an Intent passing the ImageView's bitmap to a new activity which uses a SurfaceView to render the bitmap where I hanlde zoom/panning for #3.